# function to remove square brackets from dictionaries value using python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

{"bbox": [[1386, 111], [1475, 111], [1475, 159], [1386, 159]]}

How could i get rid of square brackets of value in it, so it looks like this:

{"bbox": [1386, 111, 1475, 111, 1475, 159, 1386, 159]}

How could I write a function which would do that?

d = {k:v[0] for k,v in d.items()}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Also, it is a nested list. not a dictionary.

Comment: That isn't a dictionary. Printing it without brackets seems like a complete waste of time. The list is still going to be multidimensional, regardless of how much you destroy the printed format.

Answer (score 0):

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

which is

```
flat_list = []
for sublist in l:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)
```

function:

```
def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

Comment: As already mentioned the credit goes to the above comment.

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates; doing so complicates their eventual [removal.](/help/roomba)